# CSS Button Style not Applying

Tags: html, css, button

I'm having a problem implementing a style I put on a . I've used CSS3 for it. Locally, when I try it, it works as it should, the style is there but when I upload it on my hosting it doesn't apply the style.

Here's what I use on the HTML file:

```
<button id="liveButton" class="btn" style="padding: 10px;">Livestream</button>
```

Here's what I have on the stylesheet:

```
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
  border: solid #1f628d 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've tried different things based on what I read from several websites including some on this site but it just won't show. Typically, it should show a Blue Button but on the site it just shows a Generic/Default kind of button.

Looking for some insights into this. Thanks!

UPDATE
Fixed it by removing Password on the Directory where I uploaded it. It seems like it wasn't working because it was password protected? But that showed the style for the Button for me after I removed it.

Comment: Then most likely the path to your CSS is wrong, not the CSS rules

Comment: @LGSon Not really, the style on the Page works as it should. Only the CSS for the button isn't. I could share the link to where I uploaded it but not sure if I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working just fine. Please read this before submitting question: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> - Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
> - Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem
> - Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5;
  -moz-border-radius: 5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
  border: solid #1f628d 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="liveButton" class="btn" style="padding: 10px;">Livestream</button>
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot for better understanding. One screenshot locally and one after uploading on server.

Comment: I fixed it somehow. I think it's because I password protected the directory it is in that's why it wasn't showing as it should. I just removed it to show to you guys but it's ok now it seems.

Comment: Yeah! It was working fine, that's what I was wondering. Cheers! :)

Comment: Updated my original post as well so if anyone is or will have a problem in the future. They should check out their Password Protect if they enabled it for that.